# Unable to see add option for the task in azure build pipeline that is already Installed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-task-groups

In Azure build pipeline i need to added the "Quality Gate Widget" task and its already installed, but i'm unable to see "Add" button.

Can anyone suggest me what needs to be done - is there any that i'm missin?

Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that extension only contains a Dashboard Widget and not a pipeline task. So, you won't be able to add it to a pipeline.

You can use this Azure DevOps extension to fail builds in the event your Sonarqube quality gates don't pass:

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimondeLang.sonar-buildbreaker

Comment: Got it Thanks, I tried adding the extension to the Dashabord Widget, but its unable to fetch the details from Sonarqube.

Below is the URL that is configured, I am able to hit the endpoint in the postman/browser and able to get the details.        
 

**https://<SonarqubeServer>/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=<projectKey>**

Is there anything to be done ?

Comment: @RaghuHoskote. Please check if you having the same issue as this ticket: https://github.com/yuriburger/quality-gate-widget/issues/1 . This extension seems to have issues.

Comment: Yes, I have the exact same issue, not sure what needs to be done.

Comment: @RaghuHoskote. You settings should be correct. The extension itself has some issues. So this widget may not be able to use.